# How can I use 96kHz sampling frequency on USB audio on Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, audio, bluetooth

My system is

```
System: Ubuntu 22.04LTS
Kernel: 5.15.0-76-generic #83-Ubuntu
```

OS is up-to-date.

I bought an USB Bluetooth dongle ("Qualcomm 24Bit 96kHz USB Bluetooth 5.2 aptX HD audio").

When I plug it into my computer, please see this dmesg output:

```
[ 2996.890647] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2997.043400] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=4010, bcdDevice=18.65
[ 2997.043408] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 2997.044618] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
[ 2997.045347] hub 3-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 2997.346644] usb 3-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2997.463390] usb 3-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=1275, bcdDevice=26.13
[ 2997.463393] usb 3-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2997.463394] usb 3-1.1: Product: HaiSenKeJi
[ 2997.463405] usb 3-1.1: Manufacturer: Qualcomm
[ 2997.463407] usb 3-1.1: SerialNumber: CBCDAF0123456789
[ 2997.471913] input: Qualcomm HaiSenKeJi Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.3/0003:0A12:1275.0006/input/input19
[ 2997.530882] input: Qualcomm HaiSenKeJi as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.3/0003:0A12:1275.0006/input/input20
[ 2997.531219] hid-generic 0003:0A12:1275.0006: input,hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Qualcomm HaiSenKeJi] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1/input3
[ 2997.603033] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[ 2997.617458] usb 3-1.1: 1:1: cannot set freq 96000 to ep 0x3
[ 2997.619498] usb 3-1.1: 1:2: cannot set freq 96000 to ep 0x3
[ 2997.726438] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

These lines are red:

```
[ 2997.617458] usb 3-1.1: 1:1: cannot set freq 96000 to ep 0x3
```

And it makes sense, as when I try playing anything (YouTube, Spotify) on the computer, it sounds playing way faster than it should and it's unenjoyable.

I have two questions here:

1.) How can I install any type of GUI for these devices? I wish to chose which speaker to connect to.
2.) How can I use 96kHz (i.e. make the error message go away)? - or failsafe: how can I reduce 96kHz to 41kHz (or whatever is default)?

Anything else is missing, please let me know in comments, I'll add it. I have no idea on where to continue the diagnostics.